# Pivot data-frame with list as value in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data-frame like this:

| name | A | B | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 3 | [1,1,1] | 1 |
| y | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| z | 5 | [1,1,1] | 1 |
| x | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| y | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| z | 7 | 3 | 2 |

What I want is this:

| x_A | x_B | y_A | y_B | z_A | z_B | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | [1,1,1] | 3 | 4 | 5 | [1,1,1] | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

My code so far looks like this:

```
df = df.pivot_table(column= 'name', values =['A','B'])
df2 = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
```

However, when I run this, it seems to skip the columns that have lists (ie. column B) and gives me:

| x_A | y_A | z_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |

Is there another way to solve this? Am I missing something? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc` of `first` (to handle object types like list) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to group level 1 keys together. Then collapse the MultiIndex with [`Index.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html). Lastly, return `i` to the columns with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out_df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index='i',
        columns='name',
        aggfunc='first'
    ).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
)
out_df.columns = out_df.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)
out_df = out_df.reset_index()
```

`out_df`:

|  | i | x_A | x_B | y_A | y_B | z_A | z_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | [1, 1, 1] | 3 | 4 | 5 | [1, 1, 1] |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 3 |

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    'A': [3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7],
    'B': [[1, 1, 1], '4', [1, 1, 1], '3', '7', '3'],
    'i': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
})
```

---

The [pyjanitor](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor) module has an abstraction for this operation called [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) which simplifies this transformation to:

```
out_df = df.pivot_wider(index='i', names_from='name')
```

|  | i | x_A | y_A | z_A | x_B | y_B | z_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 5 | [1, 1, 1] | 4 | [1, 1, 1] |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 7 | 3 |

Complete Working Example:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
# conda install pyjanitor -c conda-forge
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    'A': [3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7],
    'B': [[1, 1, 1], '4', [1, 1, 1], '3', '7', '3'],
    'i': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
})

out_df = df.pivot_wider(index='i', names_from='name')
print(out_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df = df.set_index("name").stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  x_A        x_B y_A y_B z_A        z_B
0   3  [1, 1, 1]   3   4   5  [1, 1, 1]
```

---

EDIT: With updated question:

```py
df = df.set_index(["name", "i"]).unstack(level=0).swaplevel(axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)
print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   i  x_A  y_A  z_A        x_B y_B        z_B
0  1    3    3    5  [1, 1, 1]   4  [1, 1, 1]
1  2    5    5    7          3   7          3
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize. I tried to simplify my problem but it seems I simplified too much. I have since updated my question. Sorry again, I know that's bad practice. 'name' is not unique, the column 'i' is - so 'name' cannot be the unique index. Otherwise this was a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

```
from io import StringIO
df = """name    A   B
x   3   [1,1,1]
y   3   4
z   5   [1,1,1]"""
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(df)).set_index('name')
s = pd.Series(df.values.ravel(),
              index=[i+'_'+c for i in df.index for c in df.columns])
s.to_frame().T
```

|  | x_A | x_B | y_A | y_B | z_A | z_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | [1,1,1] | 3 | 4 | 5 | [1,1,1] |